# Filtering a Django queryset with a limited subquery

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to get a queryset, and limit based on a limited set of subqueries.
It seems to be returning only a limited set of the first query.

`photos = Photo.objects.filter(event=Event.objects.all().order_by('date')[:5]).order_by('event')`

I'm trying to get all photo in the five most recent events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases you have to use the `in` lookup:

```
events = Event.objects.order_by('date')[:5]
photos = Photo.objects.filter(event__in=events).order_by('event')
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I could probably also do `photos = Photo.objects.filter(event__in=Event.objects.order_by('date')[:5]).order_by('event')`, if I was trying to go the least readable route, right. :)

Comment: Right! :-) You could do it in a single line